# Main class to form class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class, text, xna

Ok, lets start over, may have not said things correctly, (don't judge me) so lets start from the beginning. Under XNA Game Studio 4.0, were the templates are stored, I selected Windows Game (4.0). I name the project `form`.

It loads:

[image: The load up of the game]

With code in `Game1.cs`. Now I right click on form, add, new item, and select windows form. I name the form `Form1.cs`.

Now it looks like this:

[image: After adding the form what the solution bar look like]

I then add a button:

[image: The form with a button in the middle of it]

if I want to display and click on the button what must I do to `Game1.cs` to get to `Form1.cs`?

Comment: You've posted empty boilerplate code for a new XNA game with nothing added to it.  You're going to have to try again to explain what you are attempting to do.  XNA games don't have forms - WinForms projects have forms.  Are you saying that you are trying to use XNA to make a splash screen for a WinForms application?  It's not clear what you have tried and what your problem is.

Comment: @J... I am sorry for the explanation, hopefully I have now fixed the problem with it.

Comment: Ok! That's a lot more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this any number of ways.  The obvious place to handle this is in the `Update` method of the game (note the TODO comment the boilerplate code leaves for you) :

```
// TODO: Add your update logic here
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.F1)) 
{
     Form1 form1 = new Form1();
     form1.ShowDialog();
}
```

The above code would check if `F1` has been pressed on each update and, if so, it would create and show the form.  I've used `ShowDialog` here as I would guess this form would be used to modify settings, etc, and you would want it to remain on top.

Now, if you use the above code you quickly find a problem - an XNA game's `Update` method is continuously being called.  Even a quick tap of the key will end up creating several new windows and showing them so you need to implement some means of interlocking entry into the form.  An easy way to do this is to declare a boolean in `Game1.cs`

```
  private bool isForm1Open = false;
```

and then in the `Update` method :

```
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.F1) && (!isForm1Open)) 
{
   isForm1Open = true;
   Form1 form1 = new Form1();
   form1.FormClosed += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler(
                         (s, e) => { isForm1Open = false; } );
   form1.ShowDialog();
}
```

This attaches an anonymous event handler to `form1` to reset `isForm1Open` when it closes.  This guarantees that the form only opens once.  In any case, showing a form is the same as you would usually do it - create a new one and show it.  There are other ways, of course, to hande this - you may want to implement `Form1` as a singleton class or perhaps just keep a copy in memory and use show/hide instead.  This will depend on what you have in mind for this form and how you intend it to work.

Comment: I understand basic logic of C# XNA, thank you for the help I will test it tomorrow, I do not have access to my program to see if it is correct.